# Pass a variable to a function\Return a new value with that variable\Repeat until value reaches 0

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm having issues understanding how to properly pass a user input value to a function, subtract 1 from that value, return the new value, and place the new value in a loop. So each time the loop executes, it will send the updated value to the function, eventually reaching/stopping at 0. This is what I have so far.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getBottles(int num);

int main()
{
int num;
int run;
int numBottles;

cout << "Enter the amount of bottle to start with: ";
cin >> num;


if ((num < 0) || (num > 101)) {
    cout << "Error! Number isnt valid!\n";
    return main();
}
else
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= run; --i)
    {
        numBottles = getBottles(num);
        cout << "Number of beers on the wall " << numBottles;
    }

}
return 0;
}


int getBottles(int num) {

do {
    num = num - 1;

} while (num > 0);
return num;
}
```

Comment: First choose a language.

Comment: I think, you need to use Rubber Duck Debugging technique described here: https://rubberduckdebugging.com/ to fix your code.

Answer (score 2):

int getBottles will subtract 1 from num while num > 0, instead of just once.

Try something like

```
int getBottles(int num) {
    return num-1;
}
```

And here you're using

```
for (size_t i = 0; i <= run; --i)
```

Where run is uninitialized, and you decrement i starting from 0.

Try something like

```
while (num) {
    cout << "Number of beers on the wall " << num;
    num = getBottles(num);
}
```

If you want it to stop before printing out there's no beers on the wall left.

Comment: In `numBottles = getBottles(num);` `num` will remain unchanged. Infinite loop. Get rid of `num` in favor of `numBottles` or replace `numBottles`  with `num`. Your choice.

Comment: Good catch! I didn't notice.